# Making words from two lists match

Tags: c#, list

I have two lists and want to generate a result where words will be logically connected. For example - "man is alive", "rat is an animal" etc.

```
List<string> nouns = new List<string> { man[1], woman[2], cat[3], house[4], rat[5], prison[6]};

List<string> descriptions = new List<string> { is alive[1][2][3][5], is made of bricks[4][6], is an animal[3][5], is a building[4][6], is female[2][3][5], is a word [1][2][3][4][5][6]};
```

As I understand I need to populate a hashtable using these lists first? How do I do it? Should I add special indexes inside the lists first?

I see it as some hashtable where all first words have indexes like Man(1), woman (2) etc, and then all descriptions match ONLY the right words like "is alive (1), is a word (1)". "is alive (2), is female (2), is alive (2)". I'd like to know how to do it.

Comment: What is the logic you want to use to connect the lists?

Comment: "Woman is made of bricks" - That would be nice. In a more serious tone, It doesn't look like both your lists are index aligned to fit what you're doing, that means that you'll need to semantically understand that a rat is an animal.

Comment: Is it a question about AI? Please concretize your task.

Comment: I want to use logic of my own. I want to create rules so that I do not get "a woman is made of bricks" using special indexes.

Comment: Well, if you have your own rules, you need to show us what you've attempted to do. Your question is too general.

Comment: I changed the strings inside the lists to show what I mean.

Comment: @SergZ you should modify your `List<string> nouns`, make this a `List<Noun>` where a 'Noun` type knows about what descriptions make sense for it

Comment: How big is the list of descriptions/nouns? Is it prone to change in the future?

Comment: @CarbineCoder - yes, they can be pretty big and changed in future.

Comment: TimSchmelter's Solution is cleaner. But as you mentioned this list is bound to change in the future, so if a description is removed in the future the nounDescriptions will no longer be relavant as it relies on the index. I am not too sure about Dmitry Bychenko's answer solves this problem by keeping the relation at the description rather than at the noun end. But again if the list is huge i am not sure about the impact of parsing everything. A relational database holding these references would be an optiomal solution. Getting how do to it is a bigger question.

Answer (score 4):

If there is no logic but the index you want to use to connect the lists you can use `Enumerable.Zip`:

```
IEnumerable<string> result = nouns
    .Zip(descriptions, (n, d)=> String.Format("{0} {1}", n, d));
```

Result:

```
"man is alive"  
"woman is made of bricks"   
"cat is an animal"  
"house is a building"   
"rat is female" 
"prison is a word"
```

---

Now that your question has changed and you have clarified things it seems that you don't want two lists but one `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`. So the value contains all indexes of the strings which belong to the noun.

```
var nounDescriptions = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>
{
       {"man", new List<int>{0, 1, 2, 4}},
       // .....
};
foreach (var kv in nounDescriptions)
    foreach(int index in kv.Value)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", kv.Key, descriptions[index]);
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP is looking for apparently.

Comment: +1 had never heard of [Enumerable.Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: i don't know. What does he want instead? Edit: Now i've seen the comment, but i still dont know what he actually wants.

Comment: Look at his updated question. He's asking how to implement semantic knowledge between a noun and a description.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: he could use a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` instead where the list contains all indexes in the other list. Or a ``Dictionary<string, List<string>>`` where the value list stores the descriptions redundant. I've editedmy answer.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution with *parsing* (if I've got the format right):

```
  List<string> nouns = new List<string> { 
    "man[1]", "woman[2]", "cat[3]", "house[4]", "rat[5]", "prison[6]"};

  List<string> descriptions = new List<string> { 
    "is alive[1][2][3][5]", 
    "is made of bricks[4][6]", 
    "is an animal[3][5]", 
    "is a building[4][6]", 
    "is female[2][3][5]", 
    "is a word [1][2][3][4][5][6]" };

  // parsed dictionary of entry indice
  var dict = descriptions
    .Select(item => item.Split(new Char[] { '[', ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .SelectMany(items => items.Skip(1).Select(item => new {
      name = items[0],
      id = int.Parse(item) }))
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.id, pair => pair.name)
    .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item);

  var result = nouns
    .Select(item => item.Split(new Char[] { '[', ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .SelectMany(items => items.Skip(1).Select(item => new {
      name = items[0],
      id = int.Parse(item)}))
    .SelectMany(pair => dict[pair.id].Select(item => pair.name + " " + item));
```

To print out:

```
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome is

```
man is alive
man is a word 
woman is alive
woman is female
woman is a word 
cat is alive
cat is an animal
cat is female
cat is a word 
house is made of bricks
house is a building
house is a word 
rat is alive
rat is an animal
rat is female
rat is a word 
prison is made of bricks
prison is a building
prison is a word
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Code

```
Dictionary<string, string> nouns = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "man", "word,human,animal" },
    { "woman", "word,human,animal,female" },
    { "cat", "word,animal" },
    { "house", "word,construction" },
    { "rat", "word,animal" },
    { "prison", "word,construction" },
};

Dictionary<string, string> descriptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "alive", "animal" },
    { "is made of bricks", "construction" },
    { "is an animal", "animal" },
    { "is female", "female" },
    { "is a word", "word" },
};

Dictionary<string, List<string>> nounsByTag =
    (from e in nouns
     select new
     {
         Word = e.Key,
         Tags = (from t in e.Value.Split(',') select t.Trim()).Distinct()
     })
        .SelectMany((a, b) => a.Tags, (a, b) => new { Word = a.Word, Tag = b })
        .GroupBy(e => e.Tag, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        .Select(e => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(e.Key, e.Select(x => x.Word).ToList()))
        .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);


Dictionary<string, List<string>> descriptionsByTag =
    (from e in descriptions
     select new
     {
         Word = e.Key,
         Tags = (from t in e.Value.Split(',') select t.Trim()).Distinct()
     })
        .SelectMany((a, b) => a.Tags, (a, b) => new { Word = a.Word, Tag = b })
        .GroupBy(e => e.Tag, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        .Select(e => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(e.Key, e.Select(x => x.Word).ToList()))
        .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);

var result = (from n in nounsByTag
              join d in descriptionsByTag on n.Key equals d.Key
              select new
              {
                  Nouns = n.Value,
                  Descriptions = d.Value
              }).ToList();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    foreach (string noun in item.Nouns)
    {
        foreach (string desc in item.Descriptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", noun, desc);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Result

```
man is a word
woman is a word
cat is a word
house is a word
rat is a word
prison is a word
man alive
man is an animal
woman alive
woman is an animal
cat alive
cat is an animal
rat alive
rat is an animal
woman is female
house is made of bricks
prison is made of bricks
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> temp = new List<string>();
if(nouns.Count == descriptions.Count)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < nouns.Count; i++)
    {
        temp.Add(string.format("{0} {1}", nouns[i], descriptions[i]));
    }
}
```

Or with Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
if (nouns.Count == descriptions.Count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nouns.Count; i++)
    {
        dict.Add(nouns[i], descriptions[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Dictionary with nouns as keys

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dictionary.Add("man","is alive");// "man" as key and "is alive" is value
.......
string description = dictionary["man"]; // the result will be "is alive"
```